# Partition a hive table with a column in middle from another external table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have created an external table as below:

```
create external table if not exists complaints (date_received string, product string, sub_product string, issue string, sub_issue string, consumer_complaint_narrative string, state string, company_public_response string, company varchar(50), zipcode int, tags string, consumer_consent_provided string, submitted_via string, date_sent_company string, company_response string, timely_response string, consumer_disputed string, complaint_id int) row format delimited fields terminated by ',' stored as textfile location 'hdfs:hostname:8020/complaints/';
```

Now I want to create another table complaints_new with partition as state and have all the data from above table. How can this be acheived?

I tried the below:

```
create external table if not exists complaints_new (date_received string, product string, sub_product string, issue string, sub_issue string, consumer_complaint_narrative string, company_public_response string, company varchar(50), zipcode int, tags string, consumer_consent_provided string, submitted_via string, date_sent_company string, company_response string, timely_response string, consumer_disputed string, complaint_id int) partitioned by (state varchar(20)) row format delimited fields terminated by ',' stored as textfile location 'hdfs://hostname:8020/complaints/';

SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict;
SET hive.mapred.mode = nonstrict;

insert into table complaints_new partition(state) select * from complaints;
```

The query is failing.

Comment: How is it failing? Please provide error logs. And `create external table if not exists` will not create table if it is already exists. drop and create without `if not exists` option to make sure the table is recreated correctly

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems here... you are pointing to the same location which means that you will be reading and overwriting that location... the other problem is that Hive expect th partition column to be the last element in your list, it means that you cannot do select *, instead you have to select field to field and put the state and the end of your select statement